# Accessing Magento site on lan

Tags: php, magento, lan

I am using WAMP, i have a magento project along with other php projects. All except magento project are accessible over LAN. In my office the IP that is alloted is a dynamic one, and changes upon reconnection. The problem is, upon fixing the IP in configuration--> web --> url,
the project runs, but soon after reconnection the magento project is not accessible on localhost nor on LAN (due to IP change). I am looking for a solution, that will make magento listen to current system IP when its online and also to localhost when its offline.

Comment: You can use `Listen *` to listen on all IPs on the machine. or `Listen *:80` if you want to listen on only port 80

Answer (score 0):

You should change your HOSTS file like this

```
127.0.0.1   anydomain.com
```

then change the record in the table [core_config_data] where the column [path = web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url] to http://anydomain.com
Go to admin page and flush magento cache.

Hope this work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
First do this 
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/

Then Add this to C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.